# Waiting for Callback Function to Finish : Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, callback

I want to change the view when the user logs in from the LoginController. When access = true, change controller. However, I cant do it within the user.login because it gives me an error saying I have to process this on the main thread. Now I know that there are solutions for this, but I have been searching for a week and ran around in circles. I have gotten close enough to produce what I have below.

I have 3 pieces of information that I would like to share: 
LoginController:

```
var access = false
        user.login(
            {(response: Bool) -> () in
                access = response
                print(access)
            },username: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!)
        if(access){
            print("YAY")
            let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsFeed") as! NewsFeed
            presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("NAY")
        }
```

LoginClass:

```
func login(completionHandler : (response: Bool) -> (), username: String, password: String){
    //Set the calback with the calback in the function parameter
    let parameters : [String: AnyObject] = ["tag": "login", "email": username, "password": password]
    manager.postDataToServer(
        {(response: NSDictionary) -> () in
            if(response["success"] as! Int == 1){
                // Log user in
            }else{
                // User not able to login

                }
                completionHandler(response: false)
            }
        }, page: "login", params: parameters)
}
```

APIManager:

```
func postDataToServer(completionHandler: (response: NSDictionary) -> (), page: String, params: [String: AnyObject]){
    // Gets the information and returns the User
    // Works completely fine

}
```

**ANSWER : Please go down to look at the Updated Answer**

Please look at @Rob's answer. However you may get an error message saying *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'*. It is because you cannot change views unless its on the main thread. Simply wrap it in

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        //Change View
    }
```

**Updated**
I realized my mistake was that I didn't endEditing in one of my fields before processing the information. I fixed it by doing the following, passwordField.endEditing and also emailField.endEditing (just to be safe)

Comment: BTW, is `manager` calling its closure on the main thread? If you're using AFNetworking or Alamofire, they'll generally use the main queue, but if it's code you've written yourself, you'll want to make sure you dispatch this completion handler to the main queue.

Comment: I am not sure, could I send an email out to you so you can check my APIManager code?

Comment: See my Stack Overflow profile for a "contact me" link. But, no offense, I'd rather not go through your API code. :) If you're using `NSURLSession`, make sure you do the `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { ... }` (or `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }`) of the completion handler.

Comment: haha, no problem. Looks like I haven't implemented it. It works thus far but I have lots more calls with this API so I rather get it right the first time. I will search the internet for help with it. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the response, just move the code you want to perform inside the closure:

```
user.login( { response in
    if response {
        print("YAY")
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsFeed") as! NewsFeed
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("NAY")
    }
}, username: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!)
```

Even better, I'd change the order of those parameters, so that the closure was the last parameter (and you can then use "trailing closure" syntax):

```
func loginWithUsername(username: String, password: String, completionHandler : (response: Bool) -> ()) {
    // your login code here
}
```

And then:

```
user.loginWithUsername(emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { response in
    if response {
        print("YAY")
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsFeed") as! NewsFeed
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("NAY")
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my initial go to however this is the message I get:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: That's probably stemming from where you're calling this from (perhaps from within one of the `UITextField` delegate methods?). Show us where you're calling this. But, to your question, adding code to wait is invariably the wrong answer, so let's look at where you're calling this from.

Comment: You were correct, I was using the simulator and the keyboard was still up. Upon clicking login, I added the code that says, "passwordField.endEditing(true) and it worked like a charm. (Without having to use NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock